# Is value in range with bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In **bash** shell, how can be value checked if within range by most effective way?

Example:

```
     now=`date +%H%M`

     if [ $now -ge 2245 ] && [ $now -le 2345 ] ; then
     ...
     fi
```

...this one is working, but with using `now` variable.

Other option is:

```
     if [ $((`date +%H%M`)) -ge 2245 ] && [ $((`date +%H%M`)) -le 2345 ] ; then
     ...
     fi
```

...without variable, but with execution of `date` twice.

How to do it with one `date` execution and no variable at all?

Comment: why is this limitation imposed? using a variable seems like the sanest path to take, executing `date +%H%M` twice in one command could yield different outputs if executed near whole minute time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, as a general rule, I'm pretty sure you need EITHER to use a variable OR run the command twice to do multiple comparisons on arbitrary numbers.  There is no such notation as `if [ 1000 -lt $(date '+%H%M') -lt 2000 ];`.

Also, you don't need to put your backquoted commands inside $((...)).  The result of the backquoted command is a string which `/bin/[` will be interpreted by -gt or -le as a number.

```
if [ `date '+%H%M'` -gt 2245 -a `date '+%H%M'` -lt 2345 ]; then
```

That said, as an option for the times in your example, you can try using a smarter `date` command line.

In FreeBSD:

```
if [ `date -v-45M '+%H'` -eq 22 ]; then
```

Or in Linux:

```
if [ `date -d '45 minutes ago' '+%H'` -eq 22 ]; then
```

Comment: To cut leading zero and get integer `date '+%-H%M'` should be used

Comment: No need to cut leading zeros.  Try it: `test 09 -eq 9 && echo "It works."`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Shell Arithmetic` to make your code clear.

```
now=`date +%H%M`
if ((2245<now && now<2345)); then
    ....
fi
```

Comment: This is not valid shell syntax.  It is valid in bash and some other shells, but it is not valid in general.  (Rather, the syntax is valid, but the semantics are not as described.  Rather, the shell will attempt to invoke the command 2245 with input from a file named 'now', and will likely fail when it does not find a command named 2245)

Comment: I only test it in `bash`. I've no idea in other shells.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
if ( now=$(date +%H%M) ; ! [[ $now < 2245 ]] && ! [[ $now > 2345 ]] ) ; then
    ...
fi
```

which is mostly equivalent to your first example, but restricts the `$now` variable to a subshell `(...)`, so at least it doesn't pollute your variable-space or risk overwriting an existing variable.

It also (thanks to shellter's comment) avoids the problem of `$now` being interpreted as an octal number when `%H%M` is (for example) `0900`. (It avoids this problem by using string comparison instead of integer comparison. Another way to avoid this problem would be to prefix all values with a literal `1`, adding 10,000 to each of them.)

Comment: When testing your code, I get `$ if ( now=$(date +%H%M) ; [[ $now -ge 2245 ]] && [[ $now -le 2345 ]] ) ; then     : ; fi
sh: [[: 0919: value too great for base (error token is "0919")` with `GNU bash, version 3.1.17`. Also, I don't see the purpose of using a subshell for evaluation, i.e. `( .... )`.  Finally, you can save some typing, with [[ $now -ge 2245 && $now -le 2345 ]]`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Re: octal: y'know, that's a good point. We're not comparing integers, we're comparing strings. We can just use `<` and `>`. I'll update my answer. Re: subshell: What do you mean, you don't see the purpose? I stated my purpose. Do you disagree with it? Re: saving typing: in my experience, the use of `&&` and `||` inside conditional expressions is terribly error-prone, so I prefer to always put them outside to avoid subtle bugs.

Comment: @shellter = Change `now=$(date +%H%M)` to `now=$(date +%-H%M)` and try again. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
    do
MAX_TIME="1845"
MIN_TIME="1545"
  if ( now=$(date +%H%M) ; ! [[ $now < $MIN_TIME ]] && ! [[ $now > $MAX_TIME ]] ) ;
    then
       echo "You are in time range and executing the commands ...!"
    else
       echo "Maximum Time is $MAX_TIME ...!"
      # echo "Current Time is $now .....!"
       echo "Minimum Time is $MIN_TIME ....!"           
  fi
sleep 4
done
#nohup sh /root/Date_Comp.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```